# "Missing Operating System" - Dual boot, 12.10 on MacBookPro4,1

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, system-installation

I followed [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Dual-Boot%3a_Mac_OSX_and_Ubuntu) instructions for installing Ubuntu Dual-Boot with OSX Lion, but when I finished and restarted it said "Missing Operating System". I restarted a few more times and I got the same message. Do I need to install 12.10 in a different way?
At least I didn't mess up the OSX partition.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/487716/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbook-pro-4-1/487826#487826

Comment: You might need to re-install grub boot loader on there.