# Installing ubuntu 14.04 on macbook pro 4,1

Tags: 14.04, mac, macbook-pro

I've been reading lots of posts about how to create a bootable usb and how to install but I haven't been successful.

I've created the "bootable" usb following [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) from Ubuntu site.

When I boot with Refind, my usb is not even listed.

Pressing alt/option key when rebooting I manage to have my usb listed and boot. However I get the following error message:

> Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
>   error: file `/boot/' not found.

However, a grub screen appears with the options for:

- install
- trying ubuntu without installing
- check memory

But after choosing any option I get stuck with a black screen.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you got rEFIt or rEFInd  installed? 
http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: I've tried both. Now I have Refind since I've read that Refit is no longer maintained.

Comment: which guide did you use? I don't see a link here. thanks!

Comment: Sorry @ElderGeek I've fixed the [link.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

Comment: did you check the md5 on the iso you downloaded to insure it matched before converting to img and making the usb stick?

Comment: I haven't checked the md5 before and after. 

However, I've used the two usb's I've created for booting a MacBook Air and it was able to boot ubuntu without any errors. Thus, this seems to be something wrong with compatibility with macbook pro 4,1.

Comment: @ElderGeek yes I've already seen the link you mention but I didn't find it useful.

Comment: @ElderGeek I've tried ubuntu 9.10 and 10.04 with no success. It seems that whenever I manage to see the usb listed and boot grub menu, it gets stuck booting ubuntu. This happens for >12.04 releases. For releases <12.04 the usb is not listed when booting the system.
I'll try to read carefully the guides you sent me.

Comment: The guide in my answer is specific to 10.04 (Lucid) and your macbook pro 4,1. It's been tested and should be successful.

Comment: I've tried all the guides and with older versions of ubuntu I cannot choose to boot from the usb, and with newer versions of ubuntu I can usb the usb stick to boot but only until Grub menu. :/

Comment: I've also tried to _dd_ the usb data directly to the HD partition but when booting it complains about missing isolinux.bin

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you would be better served installing 10.04 in accordance with this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro4-1/Lucid) as it's the most recent LTS release tested on your hardware. Older versions of Ubuntu are available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

If you would be interested in helping the Mactel Support team you can look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam)

you may also be interested in the [Apple Users Ubuntu Support Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328)

Comment: I'm downloading the ubuntu Lucid Lynx distro. Tomorrow I'll try to install it and I'll report the results. 
Thanks @ElderGeek .